# Basic market basket/recommendation analysis issue

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, recommendation-engine

I have a question about market basket analysis/recommendation algorithms. Using Python, I have created a very basic recommendation algorithm (if you can even call it that) for my dad's store. Basically it takes the likelihood of buying Item X and Y together as a percentage of buying Item X and anything else. (From what I understand, this is the [Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) idea)I'm trying to emulate what a huge store like Amazon does with it's "Customers who looked at this item also bought" feature.

My problem is I don't know how to filter out all the noise. For example lots of people buy bananas. So bananas always shows up as "high likelihood" for other items, even though its not related in an interesting way. Is there any other basic statistical techniques to filter out commonly bought items? My current technique lessens the impact, but it still remains.

Thanks!

Comment: [Collaborative Filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering)

Comment: Maybe use another variable? Like, type? "Tools", "Food", "Books"

Comment: While it is very interesting, I think this question is not suitable for SO since it is very broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about [Collaborative Filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering). One approach is to train a [neural network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network), usually with one hidden layer<sup>1</sup>, the input layer and output layer will have one [perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) for each item in your shop. Feed it with the products a person like, and it will result the likelihood (or classification, depending on how you trained your network) of each item to be liked by this user.

You then train the model using the existing pool of customers using [back-propogation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation)

This approach is not trying to find a person that is "similar to you" - but rather build a profile for users, and suggest items based on this profile.

Since you are using python, you could use [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) and use existing implementations of these algorithms

More advanced mechanics also exist, and in general - this area of research is constantly evolving. [Netflix Prize challenge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix_Prize) revolved around the same topic.

---

(1) The hidden layer is representing categorization - for example food, tools, books, ...  However, the algorithm find some categorizations for you, all you need to do is tell how many categories you want, in the network architecture. Having more than one hidden layer can represent sub-categories.